# converting from string to float or integer depending on their nature in python

Tags: python, string, list, integer

After parsing a file, I obtain a list of strings containing numerical values, let's say:

```
my_list = ['1', '-2.356', '00.57', '0', '-1', '02678', '0.005367', '0', '1']
```

In order to obtain these numerical values, I do the following:

```
new_list = [float(i) for i in my_list] .
```

The problem is that the integer values - which are a majority in the file I am handling, are also converted to float and thus occupy more memory - let alone other issues (I have to use some of them as indexes - thus they need to be converted to int at some point..)

Is there an efficient way to convert from string to float only those needed (I must not lose any precision) and to integer all the other ones?

Comment: You could see if the string contains a `'.'`, use that to decide whether you want `float(i)` or `int(i)`. What about floats that can be exactly represented as ints, like `1.0`?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can built a function that converts the *strings* to *integers* if possible and *floats* otherwise (and if even that fails, leave them as strings).

```
my_list = ['1', '-2.356', '00.57', '0', '-1', '02678', '0.005367', '0', '1']

def converter(n):
  try:
    return int(n)
  except ValueError:
    try:
      return float(n)
    except ValueError:
      return n  # <- left as string

print([converter(x) for x in my_list])  # -> [1, -2.356, 0.57, 0, -1, 2678, 0.005367, 0, 1]
```

This works because `int('2.3')` is not the same as `int(2.3)`. The first returns an Error while the second, *clips* the float and returns `2`.

Also note that the order in which the `try` blocks are arranged is very important since `float('2')` **does work**. As a result, casting to `int` has to be tried first!

Comment: `+one` since you also handled string ( if `int` and `float` fails)

Comment: I was going to close this question as a dupe, but I can't find a good target that gives priority to this technique, which I agree is the best way to do it, unless you can guarantee that all the strings are simple, i.e., no strings like '12E3' or 'Nan'.

Comment: + one for seeing first that it was not trivial, and proposing a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between int and float in your list is whether or not there is a `.`, you can use that to choose what casting to use.

```
new_list = [float(elt) if '.' in elt else int(elt) for elt in my_list]
```

#### edit:

In order to handle float special cases, the converter function proposed by @EvKounis is a good idea; expanding on it after @PM2Ring remark:

```
my_list = ['1', '1E3', '-inf', 'inf', 'NaN', 'nan', '-2.356', '00.57', '0', '-1', '02678', '0.005367', '0', '1', '398472398472943657410843104729572471308172374018301478744723974523987452938729847194719841471476574572394710481048075434810482398752481038185739847239847294365741084310472957247130817237401830147874472397452398745293872984719471984147147657457239471048104807543481048239875248103818573984723984729436574108431047295724713081723740183014787447239745239874529387298471947198414714765745723947104810480754348104823987524810381857398472398472943657410843104729572471308172374018301478744723974523987452938729847194719841471476574572394710481048075434810482398752481038185739847239847294365741084310472957247130817237401830147874472397452398745293872984719471984147147657457239471048104807543481048239875248103818573984723984729436574108431047295724713081723740183014787447239745239874529387298471947198414714765745723947104810480754348104823987524810381857398472398472943657410843104729572471308172374018301478744723974523987452938729847194719841471476574572394710481048075434810482398752481038185739847239847294365741084310472957247130817237401830147874472397452398745293872984719471984147147657457239471048104807543481048239875248103818573984723984729436574108431047295724713081723740183014787447239745239874529387298471947198414714765745723947104810480754348104823987524810381857398472398472943657410843104729572471308172374018301478744723974523987452938729847194719841471476574572394710481048075434810482398752481038185739847239847294365741084310472957247130817237401830147874472397452398745293872984719471984147147657457239471048104807543481048239875248103818573984723984729436574108431047295724713081723740183014787447239745239874529387298471947198414714765745723947104810480754348104823987524810381857']

def convert_to_int_or_float(elt):
    try:
        e = float(elt)
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError
    elt = elt.lower()
    if '.' in elt or 'e' in elt or 'inf' in elt or 'nan' in elt:
        pass
    else:
        e = int(elt)
    return e

[convert_to_int_or_float(e) for e in my_list]
```

#### output:

```
[1,
 1000.0,
 -inf,
 inf,
 nan,
 nan,
 -2.356,
 0.57,
 0,
 -1,
 2678,
 0.005367,
 0,
 1,
 398472398472943657410843104729572471308172374018301478744723974523987452938729847194719841471476574572394710481048075434810482398752481038185739847239847294365741084310472957247130817237401830147874472397452398745293872984719471984147147657457239471048104807543481048239875248103818573984723984729436574108431047295724713081723740183014787447239745239874529387298471947198414714765745723947104810480754348104823987524810381857398472398472943657410843104729572471308172374018301478744723974523987452938729847194719841471476574572394710481048075434810482398752481038185739847239847294365741084310472957247130817237401830147874472397452398745293872984719471984147147657457239471048104807543481048239875248103818573984723984729436574108431047295724713081723740183014787447239745239874529387298471947198414714765745723947104810480754348104823987524810381857398472398472943657410843104729572471308172374018301478744723974523987452938729847194719841471476574572394710481048075434810482398752481038185739847239847294365741084310472957247130817237401830147874472397452398745293872984719471984147147657457239471048104807543481048239875248103818573984723984729436574108431047295724713081723740183014787447239745239874529387298471947198414714765745723947104810480754348104823987524810381857398472398472943657410843104729572471308172374018301478744723974523987452938729847194719841471476574572394710481048075434810482398752481038185739847239847294365741084310472957247130817237401830147874472397452398745293872984719471984147147657457239471048104807543481048239875248103818573984723984729436574108431047295724713081723740183014787447239745239874529387298471947198414714765745723947104810480754348104823987524810381857]
```

Comment: Let's hope the OP's data doesn't contain floats in scientific notation without a decimal point, eg '12E3'.

Comment: Now it handles `NaN`, `-inf`, `inf`, and scientific notation, thanks for demanding more.

Comment: And now integers that have a value larger that the maxval of floats are also handled properly.

Comment: Ev. Kounis's technique handles all the "funny" floats without needing specific tests. But anyway, you could simplify those tests a little. Eg: `elt = elt.lower()` `if any(u in elt for u in ('.', 'e', 'inf', 'nan')): pass`

Comment: It does indeed. When I replace the case by case test with your any(statement) the code breaks for very large ints: it returns `float('inf')` instead. I have no clue why, but I've been in front of my screen for far too long to look into it for now.

Comment: Weird. If `elt` represents a very large int then `e = float(elt)` will succeed, returning `float('inf')`, as you said. But the `e = int(elt)` should also be executed, and that's what happens on my machine (running Python 3.6.0), using your `if` test or my version.